# Android Intermittent UnknownHostException on Marshmallow when on VPN

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, vpn, unknown-host

I'm hitting API endpoints to retrieve data for an app.
The app is only available in the US and I am not there, so I am using a VPN.

I've tested on multiple physical devices and emulators and and I've been intermittently getting failures due to `UnknownHostException` with the message:

> Unable to resolve host "api.host.thing": No address associated with hostname

I've only ever seen the error intermittently on emulators running API level 23, on the VPN.
I've ruled out network issues by hitting the endpoints using postman or other emulators. And also, it's always successful when not on the VPN.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I might be seeing these errors?

Comment: Hey OP, did you ever sort this out?